# How to change page content base on selector option with reactjs

Tags: reactjs, select, use-state

I got below code , every option will display a certain content in the same page , assuming im getting the content from an Array of objects   how i will perform this using useState hook.

```
<FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
          <InputLabel htmlFor="branch">Branch Name</InputLabel>
          <Select
            native
            value={state.location}
            onChange={handleChange}
            inputProps={{
              name: "location",
              id: "branch",
            }}
          >
            <option aria-label="None" value="" />
            <option value={10}>North</option>
            <option value={20}>East</option>
            <option value={30}>West</option>
          </Select>
        </FormControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the selected value in a state and render conditionally based on the value of that state :

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(10)


return (
  <>
    <select value={value} onChange={(event) => setValue(event.target.value)}>
      <option value={10}>North</option>
      <option value={20}>East</option>
      <option value={30}>West</option>
    </select>
    {value === 10 && <SomeComponent/>}
    {value === 20 && <SomeOtherComponent/>}
    {value === 30 && <SomeAnotherComponent />}
  </>
)
```